# Batching MSGraph: how to use data from previous requests in JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph

I would like to make three consequential POST requests using MS Graph: (1. Create an Office 365 group; 2. Add the requester as a member of the group; 3. Create an MS Planner Plan, and set the Group from the 1st request as its owner).

I found this nice batching feature, which seems to be available now: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching ,

but I am not sure how to pass the group ID, generated within the 1st request to the 2nd and a 3rd one, especially given that we do not have a response from the server by the time the call begins.

Answer (score 1):

The Batching capability in the Microsoft Graph relies on the OData Batching capability.
You should be able to reference previous requests using the $ token here is [some documentation](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/batch-processing/)